# How can I use CSS Variables in <source media="">?

Tags: css, css-variables

I want to use my Bootstrap breakpoints in my HTML. I defined them in the :root.

```
:root {
    --mq-xs: some value;
    --mq-sm: some value;
    --mq-md: some value;
    --mq-lg: some value;
}
```

I need to use the  element with several  children. I know you can use CSS variables in the `style=""` attribute. I want to add a `media=""` attribute to those `<source>` element, and had hoped I could do the following.

```
    <picture>
        <source srcset="..." media="(min-width: var(--mq-lg))" />
        <source srcset="..." media="(min-width: var(--mq-md))" />
        <source srcset="..." media="(min-width: var(--mq-sm))" />
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="..." />
    </picture>
```

Nothing happens.

Any alternative way to do such thing? I know you can pass CSS custom properties via JavaScript, but that seems a bit too much.

Comment: I don't think CSS variables can work with HTML attribute.

Comment: `Media` attribute is not CSS you can use them in the style attribute

Comment: @weegee you are using inline style so it's CSS not HTML attribute

Comment: @weegee this won't work: https://jsfiddle.net/f6u3w4r2/1/ (here it's a HTML attribute)

Comment: @TemaniAfif true that's what I meant. I miss interpreted your comment. Looks like the OP has to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can not call a css variable in dom just in style attribute css variables just make your css files easier to write

for your problem you can use javascript because we work here only with string example

I suggest you to forget css variable for the moment because old browser cant understand them its better to use sass or less preprocessing to do this.

so if you need to manage your var dynamicly you cant use css file you need to use javascript here a little example.

```
<picture>
        <source class="sources" srcset="..." media="(min-width: var(--mq-lg))" />
        <source class="sources" srcset="..." media="(min-width: var(--mq-md))" />
        <source class="sources" srcset="..." media="(min-width: var(--mq-sm))" />
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="..." />
 </picture>
<script>

var cssVar = {
  xs : 'same value to css var',
  sm : 'same value to css var',
  md : 'same value to css var',
  lg : 'same value to css var'
}

var sources = document.getElementsByClassName('sources')

sources[0].setAttribute('media', cssVar.lg);
sources[1].setAttribute('media', cssVar.md);
sources[2].setAttribute('media', cssVar.sm);

<script/>
```